# Recovering disk Partition from gdisk

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, mbr, gpt

I have a single hard disk on my laptop. When I was trying to install windows on it, it said that I needed to have a GPT drive. Going to this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/672436/how-can-i-change-a-drives-partition-table-from-mbr-to-gpt-without-losing-an-ntf, I ran gdisk and did the 'w' bit at the end.

However, I have a problem now that the hard disk is showing a single partition of full size without any data on it. There was close to ~200GB of data on that drive I cannot live without

Please HELP!!!

Comment: This would be the time to get that backup you so carefully run every night & restore from it. Otherwise, time to invest in recovery software.

Comment: How can I get a backup of my old MBR partition? (Running Gdisk shows that there is a protected MBR partition and a GPT partition being used). And for Recovery, what kinds of softwares are there? Please help me!

Comment: there are a myriad similar questions on here - try https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+data+format

Comment: "How can I get a backup of my old MBR partition?" - You cannot, your actions made this not possible, you made irreversible changes to your HDD.  You **might** have luck with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), if you are able to restore the original partition table, you might be able to mount the partitions in order to perform your critical backup.

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, and the data is that critical, you should seek out use a Data Recovery Service and DO NOT ATTEMPT to do anything yourself to resolve this current problem.  ANY ACTIONS on your part, unless you know exactly what you are doing, will make the problem worse and any chance of file recovery will be made impossible.

Comment: Conversion to GPT did not take even a second. Though I am still new, is it at all possible that, restoring the MBR partition table will automatically restore my HDD? I have not formatted my HDD at all, simply converted it to GPT. (Well, tried to convert it to GPT)

Comment: Have you used TestDisk, to see if it even can see the correct partition table, if it does not then reversing what you did will not be possible.  Your only hope would be a Data Recovery Service which will use a different approach using tools you don't have access too (they are very expensive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. All I had to do was to recover the lose MBR table that was overwritten by the GPT table. Testdisk discovered all my tables and I wrote them back. The data was left untouched! Thank you all who helped!